# What is inside IDL (intermediate density lipoproteïn)?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, liver, lipids, fat-metabolism

I am studying about the endogene lipidcycle in the human body and I know that VLDL (very low density lipoproteïn) is made in the liver and that it contains triglycerides and cholesterol from your food but also made in the body.

Next with that, I know that VLDL brings triglycerides to the adipose tissue (or fat tissue) and to the muscles with help of the LPL (lipoproteïnlipase) just as chylomicrons do.

Enclosed; VLDL will go over to IDL (intermediate density lipoproteïn).

But what is the definition then from IDL exactly?
Is IDL just a smaller lipoproteïn then VLDL and does it only contains a sort of 'leftover' of the triglycerides? Or does it also contains cholesterol?

And if VLDL brings the triglycerides to the muscles and fat tissue, does it only contains triglycerides then? Or does it also carry cholesterol with it? If yes, what happens with the cholesterol then?

Because my book is only telling me about the transport of triglycerides to the fat tissue and muscles, but in the beginning it also says that it carry's cholesterol, and a little further in my book it even tells it can also carry cholesterolesters from HDL...
It's getting confusing...

Hope somebody can tell me what is exactly in all the kinds of lipoproteïns, where the lipoproteïns are all made, and where the products they carry come from, and where they go to. Because my book is being very indistinct.

Comment: Which book did you  read...?

Comment: "Is IDL just a smaller lipoproteïn then VLDL and does it only contains a sort of 'leftover' of the triglycerides? Or does it also contains cholesterol?" Yes / yes  / yes.

Comment: "but in the beginning it also says that it carry's cholesterol, and a little further in my book it even tells it can also carry cholesterolesters from HDL... It's getting confusing..." - The latter emotion is "adequate". From memory I'd say:  IDL turns to LDL by shedding "even more" fatty acids (as it did when it still was VHDL (Berg/Stryer, Biochemistry), and it carries cholesterol, as it becomes LDL remnant, and as such is able to take over  chloesterolesters from HDL (the latter "confusing" in a stricter sense, I guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Taken from Fundamentals of Biochemistry (Voet et al. 2013). Note the differences in apolipoproteins between LDL and IDL, as well as the ratio triacylglycerol : cholesteryl esters between VLDL and IDL.

Comment: The question is not specific enough to elaborate? Does Voet et al. tell about different fate and function of cholesterol and triacylglyerol? What are the inferences that must be made from the numbers? I mean, any answer should not be restricted to referencing alone...sorry.